# How much support is given by appium for automation.?

Tags: ui-automation, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

We building a hybrid app for both android & IOS. we considering appium for adding automation coverage. How much support is provided by appium out of box? When i browsing the appium client library. I see methods like  `find_*` (methods works accross platforms) methods all methods look for element anywhere in the page. Does it support page object model? and xpath doesn't seems works support cross platform. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Appium support Page Object pattern. I don't think it will support cross platform XPath for Native or Hybrid applications, you would need separate UI maps, each platform would  have there own XPath locators.

Comment: Even if its for android, i am more than happy. Do you have any sample code.?

Comment: Only for iOS, I  think there is lots of tutorials on the web check out guys from toolsqa.com I think they have it in tutorials section